# Call object method from inside jQuery.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, get

So I'm getting into modular javascript and I came across a roadblock when trying to incorporate a jQuery http request into my module. I don't really know what to call this so my apologies if the title is misleading.

```
var object = {
    init: function() {
        this.loadRequest();
    },
    loadRequest: function() {
        $.get('https://myurl.com', function(data) {
            this.parseRequest.bind(this)
        });
    },
    parseRequest: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
};

object.init();
```

When I try this, Chrome tells me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

So I guess it has something to do with how I'm binding the method to my object but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: It's too late; `this` is already wrong.  You need to learn what `bind` actually does.

Comment: `$.get('https://myurl.com', this.parseRequest.bind(this) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some misunderstanding on what actually `this` refers to in different context. I strongly suggest you to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this to have a better idea of what `this` refers to because it is an important concept.

Here is a fix to your code. If you want to use the `bind()`

```
var object = {
    init: function() {
        this.loadRequest();
    },
    loadRequest: function() {
        $.get('https://myurl.com', this.parseRequest.bind(this));
    },
    parseRequest: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
};

object.init();
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtbbc74m/

Another approach commonly used is `var self = this` (Further reading: [How to use the self with object-oriented javascript and closures](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/05/14/how-to-use-the-self-with-object-oriented-javascript-and-closures/)):

```
var object = {
    init: function() {
        this.loadRequest();
    },
    loadRequest: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.get('https://myurl.com', function(data) {
            self.parseRequest(data);
        });
    },
    parseRequest: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
};

object.init();
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tz680b1c/

Comment: `$.get('https://myurl.com', this.parseRequest.bind(this) );` gives you the same result without all the fuss of a wrapper function. But regarding the wrapper, you don't really need to define the `callback` variable: you can call `.bind()` on the anonymous function directly at the point where it is passed to `$.get()`. `this.parseRequest.bind(data);` should be `this.parseRequest(data)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for pointing me out the mistake in `this.parseRequest.bind(data);`. I have copied a wrong version from JSFiddle. Moreover, `$.get('https://myurl.com', this.parseRequest.bind(this) );` is better than declaring a callback. I have updated my answer.